# What would be the pros and cons of using JQuery over express-ejs-layouts for dynamic HTML through Express?

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

What would be the pros and cons of using JQuery over express-ejs-layouts for dynamic HTML through Express?

It seems both of them can be used for generating dynamic HTML? Which one should be preferred on what basis?

Comment: What kind of details can be added here to make it acceptable on this site? @freedomn-m

Comment: From a quick google of express-ejs-layouts, it seems to be server-side for *generating* HTML (specifically with ejs) while jquery is for *manipulating* HTML once generated.

Comment: What keywords did you use to search in Google to get that result? @freedomn-m Let me know so that I too can search better.

Comment: @freedomn-m that's an excellent difference that you have mentioned. Please write an answer.

Comment: Literally *just* express-ejs-layouts - first result was the npm page with example code: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ejs-layouts